# Gridview multiple radiobuttons in a row

Tags: asp.net, gridview, radio-button

Gridview multiple radiobuttons in a row

I have three RadioButtons in a row in a Gridview. I need to get the checked status, but it never changes when you select a button. 
Here is the code:

```
    <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="venc" ID="rdo0" Checked="True" />
         </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>

       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="2° Venc.">
         <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="venc" ID="rdo3"    />
          </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>


    protected void gvCuotas_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < 5; i++)
        {
            radio = (RadioButton)fila.FindControl("rdo" + i);
            if (radio.Checked)
               {
                  vencimiento = i; //never gets here.
                  break;
               }
            }
        }
   }
```

ASP.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCuotas" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        Caption="Cuotas Pendientes"  capCellSpacing="2" CellPadding="2" 
                    HeaderStyle-BackColor="Aqua" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="80%" 
                        BorderStyle="Solid" onrowcommand="gvCuotas_RowCommand" 
                        onrowdatabound="gvCuotas_RowDataBound" >
```

Behind:

```
public partial class Cuota1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataClasses1DataContext baseAlumnos = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var cuotas = from p in baseAlumnos.Cuotas where p.Pagado.Equals(0) 
                     select new { p.Mes, p.Observacion, p.Vencimientos, p.Pagado};


        gvCuotas.DataSource = cuotas;
        gvCuotas.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Post the HTML markup of your command button?

Comment: <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Confirm" ButtonType="Button" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your Markup to include the OnRowCommand event handler in the gridview

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="OnRowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="venc" ID="rdo0" Checked="True"/>
         </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>

       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="2° Venc.">
         <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="venc" ID="rdo3"    />
          </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Confirm" ButtonType="Button" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is the code behind for OnRowCommand event handler

```
protected void OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    GridViewRow gvRow = gv.Rows[index]; 

    for (int i = 2; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var radio = (RadioButton)gvRow.FindControl("rdo" + i);
        if (radio!=null && radio.Checked)
           {
              //This point will hit for the selected radiobutton 
              break;
           }
    }
}
```

Please make sure, you are binding your data only on page load, not on page postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack){ 
        var cuotas = from p in baseAlumnos.Cuotas where p.Pagado.Equals(0) 
                 select new { p.Mes, p.Observacion, p.Vencimientos, p.Pagado};
        gvCuotas.DataSource = cuotas;
        gvCuotas.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Already have OnRowCommand in GridView markup. Also try with radio!=null and did not hit.

Comment: Please make sure, your are binding the data only on Page_Load, I have updated my answer to add this.

Comment: Yes, Im binding on Page_Load. I have others events for this gridview witch use binding as well (other sources). This radios dont use datasources.

Comment: In that case, problem probably lies with some other data binding which you did not mention in your question. I have this working locally bound to a list of string and it is working fine. You may think to add your complete markup and code. Every time, there is a data binding, it reset the radio button state.

Comment: I think I dont need to use if page.isPostBack. Added more code.

Comment: Did you try to put your data binding code as updated in the answer?

Comment: Because, when you click on the button, postback happens and if you bind your data again in the postback all the radio button state is lost and reinitialized.